# Commit a specific query inside a larger transaction in mysql (innodb)

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, innodb

I'm looking for a way to start a transaction, do some writes which can be rolled back if needed, then do a write that cannot be rolled back and then some more writes which I can then roll back.

For example:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE...
INSERT...
DELETE...
UPDATE...

INSERT... -- This must survive even if a rollback is done

UPDATE...
INSERT...
INSERT...

COMMIT TRANSACTION/ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Does that make sense? And does anyone know a good way of doing it (other than making a new database connection, which I assume would work?).

Comment: Just rollback the whole transaction, then insert the record again, and finally commit.

Comment: @Luke, hi! How are you sure this is a bug? http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8551038

Comment: @NickVolynkin Becuase the encodeURI method does not encode the following characters: ":", "/", ";", and "?" which could lead to bugs in the code if a param had one of those chars in the name or value. http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/

Comment: @Luke ok, fixed it. Looks like the answer has more bugs and the author doesn't care. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/487049/revisions

Comment: @Luke imo, if you explained the bug in detail, the edit would be approved.